# Weblogic 12c - eclipselink MOXy - Nested Composite Objects not getting unmarshalled - error 500

Tags: jakarta-ee, eclipselink, weblogic12c, unmarshalling, moxy

I am trying to develop a jpa application for weblogic 12c. I have the following 2 objects:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account", schema = "APPSTD", catalog = "")
public class CcAccountEntity {
    private String acctFolio;
    private Set<CcCustomerEntity> customers;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ACCT_FOLIO")
    public String getAcctFolio() {
        return acctFolio;
    }

    public void setAcctFolio(String acctFolio) {
        this.acctFolio = acctFolio;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "account")
    public Set<CcCustomerEntity> getCustomers() {
        return customers;
    }

    public void setCustomers(Set<CcCustomerEntity> customers) {
        this.customers = customers;
    }
}
```

and the following

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer", schema = "APPSTD", catalog = "")
public class CcCustomerEntity {
    private String custName;
    private String custSsn;
    private String custTaxIdNbr;
    private String cpPhoneNumber;
    private CcAccountEntity account;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "CUST_NAME")
    public String getCustName() {
        return custName;
    }

    public void setCustName(String custName) {
        this.custName = custName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "CUST_SSN")
    public String getCustSsn() {
        return custSsn;
    }

    public void setCustSsn(String custSsn) {
        this.custSsn = custSsn;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "CUST_TAX_ID_NBR")
    public String getCustTaxIdNbr() {
        return custTaxIdNbr;
    }

    public void setCustTaxIdNbr(String custTaxIdNbr) {
        this.custTaxIdNbr = custTaxIdNbr;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "CP_PHONE_NUMBER")
    public String getCpPhoneNumber() {
        return cpPhoneNumber;
    }

    public void setCpPhoneNumber(String cpPhoneNumber) {
        this.cpPhoneNumber = cpPhoneNumber;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ACCT_FOLIO", nullable = false)
    public CcAccountEntity getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    public void setAccount(CcAccountEntity account) {
        this.account = account;
    }
}
```

Then I have the following code to retrieve an account from the dB:

```
    public CcAccountEntity getAccount (String acctFolio) throws Exception {
        final UserTransaction utx = context.getUserTransaction();
        try {
            utx.setTransactionTimeout(120000);
            utx.begin();
            CcAccountEntity accountEntity = em.find(CcAccountEntity.class, acctFolio);

            utx.commit();

            return accountEntity;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("getAccount sql error:", e);
            try {
                utx.rollback();
            } catch (SystemException se) {
                logger.error("getAccount rollback error:", e);
            }
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Calling the last service through a rest service returns internal server error 500. I must report that this error is thrown by the weblogic and no exception is logged.
After several tries I realized that the error is thrown at line  `CcAccountEntity accountEntity = em.find(CcAccountEntity.class, acctFolio);`. Therefore, I suppose that this is MOXy problem. I must also report than when I remove the customers field from the CcAccountEntity everything works fine. Could you please help me to overcome this problem?

Comment: If em.find is throwing an exception, that seems to be related to reading in your CcAccountEntity from the database, and less of a moxy issue. Why isn't your exception handler logging your exception? You can't really track down the issue without knowing what that exception is.

Comment: Could you suggest any change so as to catch the exception?

Comment: It must be being caught, unless you are getting a throwable - so I would suspect your webLogic logging setup is just not correct or turned off. Set it up in a debugger if you can't get logging working, as a break point would allow you to inspect the error. You can also make sure your code passes through the exception through, setting the exception it gets as the cause of what ever exception you are passing to the client to get the 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

I must report that I have the following deployment errors. Also I must note that the jars that cannot be parsed are included in the /target/customercareBackend/WEB-INF/lib directory.

```
####<Ιουν 2, 2020, 10:01:50,508 πμ EEST> <Error> <J2EE> <ANIKWS121> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <8a5e9ddf-02fa-4f9a-8a0f-f8386b827432-00000013> <1591081310508> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-160248> <Unable to parse class file: zip:C:/oracle/wls12210/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/customercare-backend_war/rble4/war/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-annotations-2.10.2.jar!/module-info.class. > 
####<Ιουν 2, 2020, 10:01:50,510 πμ EEST> <Error> <J2EE> <ANIKWS121> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <8a5e9ddf-02fa-4f9a-8a0f-f8386b827432-00000014> <1591081310510> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-160248> <Unable to parse class file: zip:C:/oracle/wls12210/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/customercare-backend_war/rble4/war/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.10.1.jar!/module-info.class. > 
####<Ιουν 2, 2020, 10:01:50,511 πμ EEST> <Error> <J2EE> <ANIKWS121> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <8a5e9ddf-02fa-4f9a-8a0f-f8386b827432-00000015> <1591081310511> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-160248> <Unable to parse class file: zip:C:/oracle/wls12210/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/customercare-backend_war/rble4/war/WEB-INF/lib/jersey-common-2.31.jar!/META-INF/versions/11/org/glassfish/jersey/internal/jsr166/SubmissionPublisher$1.class. > 
####<Ιουν 2, 2020, 10:01:50,511 πμ EEST> <Error> <J2EE> <ANIKWS121> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <8a5e9ddf-02fa-4f9a-8a0f-f8386b827432-00000015> <1591081310511> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-160248> <Unable to parse class file: zip:C:/oracle/wls12210/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/customercare-backend_war/rble4/war/WEB-INF/lib/jersey-common-2.31.jar!/META-INF/versions/11/org/glassfish/jersey/internal/jsr166/SubmissionPublisher$2.class. > 
####<Ιουν 2, 2020, 10:01:50,512 πμ EEST> <Error> <J2EE> <ANIKWS121> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <8a5e9ddf-02fa-4f9a-8a0f-f8386b827432-00000015> <1591081310512> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-160248> <Unable to parse class file: zip:C:/oracle/wls12210/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/customercare-backend_war/rble4/war/WEB-INF/lib/jersey-common-2.31.jar!/META-INF/versions/11/org/glassfish/jersey/internal/jsr166/SubmissionPublisher$3.class. > 
####<Ιουν 2, 2020, 10:01:50,512 πμ EEST> <Error> <J2EE> <ANIKWS121> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <8a5e9ddf-02fa-4f9a-8a0f-f8386b827432-00000015> <1591081310512> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-160248> <Unable to parse class file: zip:C:/oracle/wls12210/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/customercare-backend_war/rble4/war/WEB-INF/lib/jersey-common-2.31.jar!/META-INF/versions/11/org/glassfish/jersey/internal/jsr166/SubmissionPublisher$4.class. > 
####<Ιουν 2, 2020, 10:01:50,512 πμ EEST> <Error> <J2EE> <ANIKWS121> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <8a5e9ddf-02fa-4f9a-8a0f-f8386b827432-00000015> <1591081310512> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-160248> <Unable to parse class file: zip:C:/oracle/wls12210/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/customercare-backend_war/rble4/war/WEB-INF/lib/jersey-common-2.31.jar!/META-INF/versions/11/org/glassfish/jersey/internal/jsr166/SubmissionPublisher$5.class. > 
####<Ιουν 2, 2020, 10:01:50,512 πμ EEST> <Error> <J2EE> <ANIKWS121> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <8a5e9ddf-02fa-4f9a-8a0f-f8386b827432-00000015> <1591081310512> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-160248> <Unable to parse class file: zip:C:/oracle/wls12210/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/customercare-backend_war/rble4/war/WEB-INF/lib/jersey-common-2.31.jar!/META-INF/versions/11/org/glassfish/jersey/internal/jsr166/SubmissionPublisher$6.class. > 
####<Ιουν 2, 2020, 10:01:50,513 πμ EEST> <Error> <J2EE> <ANIKWS121> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <8a5e9ddf-02fa-4f9a-8a0f-f8386b827432-00000015> <1591081310513> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-160248> <Unable to parse class file: zip:C:/oracle/wls12210/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/customercare-backend_war/rble4/war/WEB-INF/lib/jersey-common-2.31.jar!/META-INF/versions/11/org/glassfish/jersey/internal/jsr166/SubmissionPublisher.class. > 
####<Ιουν 2, 2020, 10:01:50,515 πμ EEST> <Error> <J2EE> <ANIKWS121> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <8a5e9ddf-02fa-4f9a-8a0f-f8386b827432-00000015> <1591081310515> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-160248> <Unable to parse class file: zip:C:/oracle/wls12210/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/customercare-backend_war/rble4/war/WEB-INF/lib/jersey-common-2.31.jar!/META-INF/versions/11/org/glassfish/jersey/internal/jsr166/SubmissionPublisherFactory.class. > 
####<Ιουν 2, 2020, 10:01:50,565 πμ EEST> <Error> <J2EE> <ANIKWS121> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '10' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <8a5e9ddf-02fa-4f9a-8a0f-f8386b827432-00000016> <1591081310565> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-160248> <Unable to parse class file: zip:C:/oracle/wls12210/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/customercare-backend_war/rble4/war/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.10.2.jar!/module-info.class. > 
####<Ιουν 2, 2020, 10:01:50,568 πμ EEST> <Error> <J2EE> <ANIKWS121> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <8a5e9ddf-02fa-4f9a-8a0f-f8386b827432-00000017> <1591081310568> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-160248> <Unable to parse class file: zip:C:/oracle/wls12210/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/customercare-backend_war/rble4/war/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.6.jar!/module-info.class. > 
####<Ιουν 2, 2020, 10:01:50,571 πμ EEST> <Error> <J2EE> <ANIKWS121> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <8a5e9ddf-02fa-4f9a-8a0f-f8386b827432-00000018> <1591081310571> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-160248> <Unable to parse class file: zip:C:/oracle/wls12210/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/customercare-backend_war/rble4/war/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar!/META-INF/versions/9/javax/xml/bind/ModuleUtil.class. > 
####<Ιουν 2, 2020, 10:01:50,572 πμ EEST> <Error> <J2EE> <ANIKWS121> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <8a5e9ddf-02fa-4f9a-8a0f-f8386b827432-00000018> <1591081310572> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-160248> <Unable to parse class file: zip:C:/oracle/wls12210/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/customercare-backend_war/rble4/war/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar!/module-info.class. > 
####<Ιουν 2, 2020, 10:01:50,696 πμ EEST> <Error> <J2EE> <ANIKWS121> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '7' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <8a5e9ddf-02fa-4f9a-8a0f-f8386b827432-00000019> <1591081310696> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-160248> <Unable to parse class file: zip:C:/oracle/wls12210/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/customercare-backend_war/rble4/war/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar!/module-info.class. >
```